# With jQuery, how do I strip away '.html' so I can refer to the specific page as a class and/or id

Tags: jquery

I have various stories  I want to `.load()` into an empty div. I've created a menu of li ids.
Each story also has its own unique CSS page. I want to use each story's page name (minus '.html') as its id and also class.

Can anyone tell me if the following is correct?

```
$(document).ready(
         function load(page) {

                 var thisClass = page.substring(0, indexOf('.html');

                 $("#articleDiv").removeClass().addClass('"container ' + thisClass + '"').load('/PParticles/' + page);


   }
);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried the code?

Answer (score 2):

you're missing one bracket `)`

```
         var thisClass = page.substring(0, indexOf('.html'));
```

Whole could look like

```
function load(page) {
      var thisClass = page.substring(0, indexOf('.html'));
      $("#articleDiv").removeClass().addClass('"container ' + thisClass + '"').load('/PParticles/' + page);
}
```